# Using async to process commands in order, no await warning

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a C# Windows Store app with a streamsocket listener running in a task waiting for commands to come in over the network. I need to make sure each command is fully processed before doing the next one.

The listener takes a raw message and does

```
await ProcessMessage(message);
```

which is

```
private async Task ProcessMessage(string message, string optionalFlags = "")
```

Which parses the message and calls one of many methods, i.e.

```
ProcessCommandXYZ(parameters);
```

This seems to work, but in the async task ProcessMessage line I get a CS1998 "async method lacks 'await'" warning, and searching says if you get this message you're probably not using async correctly.

Is my approach correct and can I ignore this warning, or is there a better way to do this?

***Update***

I realize a lot of my problem is one of the methods is updating the state which is bound to a listview, so it's in a UI dispatcher and makes it get out of sync and I was awaiting it's ProcessCommandABC(). Since it's just the one method I believe I can optimize if that's best and don't await the one method?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of using `async` is so that you can use the keyword `await` in that function/method. Because the `ProcessMessage` method is not doing any awaits inside it, the compiler is giving you that warning. The solution is simple: remove the `async` from `ProcessMessage`. The use of `await` by a caller does not require that the method it is calling be declared with `async`. The method just needs to be returning a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Mayoor, the lack of `awaits` in the `ProcessMessage` suggests it is doing synchronous work, in which case it shouldn't be `async`. Declaring a method as `async` does not make it asynchronous it simply allows you to use `await` inside it to wait for asynchronous work to complete.

if the work is synchronous, you can run it in the background using `Task.Run` which you can `await`. So one possible solution is to make your `ProcessMessage` method synchronous and then just call

```
await Task.Run(() => ProcessMessage(...));
```

You can learn more about `async-await` best practices in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question, I've updated the main post - the real issue is a dispatcher is causing the commands to get out of order